# ordinary least square - What is the variance of Y with fixed X

Tags: regression, variance

If $Y_i = \alpha + \beta x_i + \epsilon_i $ with fixed $x_i$ and $\epsilon_i ~ N(0, \sigma^2)$. Then what is the variance of $Y$? I know that the variance of $Y_i$ is $\sigma^2$, but I don't know how to derive the variance of $Y$, that is the variance of $Y$ without given $X$. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are known for each x$_i$ the mean of y$_i$ is $\alpha$ + $\beta$ x$_i$ and the variance is just $\sigma^2$ regardless of the value of x$_i$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still don't get what do you mean with "without given X". Variance for any variable is calculated the same way:

[image]

Remember: Any variable has it own variance. When you consider another variable, then you are talking about covariance.

Comment: $var(Y) = E[(Y- E[Y])^2]$ but how do I derive this variance given the above mention condition. That is what I am trying to ask. What you've given is an sample estimation of the population variance, but I am asking to derive the variance of Y directly from the given assumptions.

Comment: "..then you are talking about covariance" or conditional variance.

Comment: From some notes I have: E[Y-E[Y]]^2=   E[Y - mY]^2 (where m= mean) Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 2):

If $X_i$ is a constant:
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{Var}[Y_i] &= \operatorname{Var}[\alpha + \beta x_i + \epsilon_i]\\
&= \operatorname{Var}[ \epsilon_i]\\
&= \sigma^2.
\end{align*}

If $X_i$ is a random variable:
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{Var}[Y_i \mid X_i] &= \operatorname{Var}[\alpha + \beta x_i + \epsilon_i\mid X_i]\\
&= \operatorname{Var}[ \epsilon_i\mid X_i]\\
&= \sigma^2,
\end{align*}
and by law of total variance:
$$
\operatorname{Var}[Y_i] = E[\operatorname{Var}[Y_i \mid X_i]] + \operatorname{Var}[E[Y_i \mid X_i]] = \sigma^2 + \operatorname{Var}[\alpha + \beta X_i] = \sigma^2 + \beta^2 \operatorname{Var}[X_i].
$$

Does this help? I'm not sure I know the difference between $Y_i$ and $Y$.

Comment: Thank you Taylor. I think what I am trying to say is, do we know the variance of Yi or expectation of Yi, if we do not know Xi/xi. that is if we consider Yi as a random variable without any knowledge of X, if this makes any sense. It seems to me that we can't even calculate E[Yi] if we have no knowledge of xi/Xi. Is this correct?

Comment: @I-PINGOu no you can, but you would need to assume a mean for $X$. This comes from the law of total expectation: $E[Y] = E[E(Y|X)] = E[\alpha + \beta X] = \alpha +\beta E[X]$.